# JQuery script inside of functions.php not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can't get this Jquery script to work inside my function.php wordpress file for a custom theme. Can someone help me. The problem is when I go to the custom post type in my wordpress admin when I click the browse button to insert an image it doesn't let me, it simply does nothing.

Here is the code (yes there is a opening php tag it just isn't shown.)

```
function show_your_images_meta_box() {
global $post;  
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_images', true ); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="your_meta_box_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( basename(__FILE__) ); ?>">

    <p>
        <label for="your_images[image]">Upload Poster Image</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="your_images[image]" id="your_images[image]" class="meta-image regular-text" value="<?php echo $meta['image']; ?>">
        <input type="button" class="button image-upload" value="Browse">
    </p>
    <div class="image-preview"><img src="<?php echo $meta['image']; ?>" style="max-width: 250px;"></div>


    <script> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
            var meta_image_frame;
            // Runs when the image button is clicked.
            $('.image-upload').click(function(e) {
                // Prevents the default action from occuring.
                e.preventDefault();
                var meta_image = $(this).parent().children('.meta-image');
                // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
                if (meta_image_frame) {
                    meta_image_frame.open();
                    return;
                }
                // Sets up the media library frame
                meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
                    title: meta_image.title,
                    button: {
                        text: meta_image.button
                    }
                });
                // Runs when an image is selected.
                meta_image_frame.on('select', function() {
                    // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
                    var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                    // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
                    meta_image.val(media_attachment.url);
                    //var image_url = meta_image.val();
                    //$(selected).closest('div').find('.image-preview').children('img').attr('src', image_url);
                });
                // Opens the media library frame.
                meta_image_frame.open();
            });
        });

    </script>

    <?php }
```

Comment: Tried watching errors in browser console? can you paste the resultant javascript that may be easier to debug?

Comment: Consider [Enqueueing Scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Comment: It's always better to enqueue your script in the admin area using [admin_enqueue_scripts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts). You can event check the hook, custom post type etc. and load your script only on that page, and not the other pages (less chance of a conflict).

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the jQuery that ships with Wordpress is set by default in compatibility mode, which means the $ shortcut doesn't work. See here: [Using ‘$’ instead of ‘jQuery’ in WordPress](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/).